# I need to get name and count value in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got a table like this

table userReport

| id | name | surname | userId | resulId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test | test | 123 | 1 |
| 2 | test | test | 123 | 1 |
| 3 | test | test | 123 | 2 |
| 4 | test | test | 123 | 3 |
| 5 | john | test | 124 | 3 |
| 6 | john | test | 124 | 2 |
| 7 | john | test | 124 | 1 |
| 8 | james | test | 125 | 3 |
| 9 | james | test | 125 | 2 |

My sql is trying to get name sunrame and count how many and also needed with resultId=1

```sql
SELECT
 name+' '+ surname
,count(userId) AS userCount
FROM [userReport]
GROUP BY userId
```

it gives error

> Column 'userReport.name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
> Column 'userReport.surname' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

also I want to add a where for `resultId = 1` in the same select

So its be like joining  the theese three selections  in one

```sql
select   name+' '+ surname   from [userReport]    
select  count(userId) as userCount   from   [userReport]  group by userId
select  count(userId) as resultCount   from   [userReport]  where resulId='1' group by userId
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest fix might be to just add the name and surname to the `GROUP BY` clause:

```sql
SELECT userId, name + ' ' + surname AS full_name, COUNT(*) AS userCount
FROM userReport
GROUP BY userId, name + ' ' + surname;
```

Note that I have also added `userId` to the `SELECT` clause.  You might want to do this in the event that two users happen to have the same first and last name.

Comment: But is this a good idea to grouping by strings join

Comment: @masterAvatarr Performance wise it's not necessarily the best thing, but you may not have a choice.

Comment: Okay i changed a bit and then worked .But  do i have to group each column i want to select

Comment: Yes, in general every column which appears in the `SELECT` has to also appear in the `GROUP BY` _unless_ that column appears inside an aggregate function such as `MIN` or `MAX`.